# JSP syntax error on token ")", delete this token

Tags: jsp

```
<%@ page import=com.linkedlistwithnode.LinkedList,com.linkedlistwithnode.Node %>

<html>
<body>

<%
    LinkedList e = new LinkedList();
    e.add(10);
    e.add(15);
    e.add(20);
%> <-this is problem!!
<%= out.println(e) %>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I imported existing linked list class in jsp. When I create a new object
it says "JSP syntax error on token ")", delete this token", what is wrong?

Sorry I am just a JSP beginner.

My understanding is that <%@ lets you import java classes into your jsp
and <% lets you write Java code, where I created a linked list object named "e", then <%= lets you print out the toString() value of the created object, through JSP object "out".

Where am I wrong?

Comment: change `<%= out.println(e) %>` into `<%= e %>` and use import like this `<%@ page import="java.util.LinkedList" %>`

Comment: Thank you for your advice! @tarashypka but this does not solve the issue 
still getting the same issue even after deleting e.add();

so all i have is <% LinkedList e = new LinkedList(); %> but this raises error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the value for the import attribute in your page directive. Also, use @tarashypka suggestion for JSP expression. Here is a demonstration.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.LinkedList" %>
<%
    LinkedList e = new LinkedList();
    e.add(10);
    e.add(15);
    e.add(20);
%> 
<html>
<body>
<%=e%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After putting <% ... %> above <html> tag, it works. Thank you